# How to execute a program that is not on PATH using Rascal

Tags: rascal

I'm trying to execute a program on Ubuntu using the `exec` or `createProcess` function, but whenever I do so I get an error that I cannot explain. E.g.:

```
rascal>import util::ShellExec;
ok
rascal>import IO;
ok
rascal>exists(|home:///Desktop/testProgram|);
bool: true
rascal>exec("./testProgram", workingDir=|home:///Desktop|);
|std:///util/ShellExec.rsc|(417,856,<16,0>,<32,124>): Java(
  "IOException",
  "Cannot run program \"./testProgram\": error=2, No such file or directory",
  Java("IOException","error=2, No such file or directory"))
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(|unknown:///ProcessBuilder.java|(0,0,<1128,0>,<1128,0>))
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(|unknown:///ProcessBuilder.java|(0,0,<1071,0>,<1071,0>))
        at org.rascalmpl.library.util.ShellExec.createProcessInternal(|unknown:///ShellExec.java|(0,0,<128,0>,<128,0>))
        at org.rascalmpl.library.util.ShellExec.createProcess(|unknown:///ShellExec.java|(0,0,<48,0>,<48,0>))
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(|unknown:///NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java|(0,0,<0,0>,<0,0>))
        at *** somewhere ***(|std:///util/ShellExec.rsc|(417,856,<16,0>,<32,124>))
        at createProcess(|std:///util/ShellExec.rsc|(1557,3,<40,81>,<40,84>))
        at $root$(|prompt:///|(0,52,<1,0>,<1,52>)ok
```

The mentioned `testProgram` is simply the following compiled C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("test program\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Executing programs that are on PATH works just fine. E.g.:

```
rascal>exec("echo", args=["test"]);
str: "test\n"
```

Especially odd to me is the fact that `at createProcess(|std:///util/ShellExec.rsc|(1557,3,<40,81>,<40,84>))` points to the identifier `env` on the second line in this code block (the `createProcess` call):

```
public str exec(str processCommand, loc workingDir=|cwd:///|, list[str] args = [], map[str,str] env = ()) {
   pid = createProcess(processCommand, workingDir=workingDir, args=args, envVars=env);
   result = readEntireStream(pid);
   killProcess(pid);
   return result;
}
```

I can't figure out how this argument connects to the command that I am trying to execute or to a file or directory not existing.

What is going wrong here? Is it not possible to execute files that are not on PATH or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `createProcess` and `exec` are not ready to understand all the abstract schemes (like `home:///`) I changed your example to `file:///Users/myname/Desktop`, and then it worked.

Comment: see https://github.com/usethesource/rascal/issues/1608

Comment: this is now fixed and also a way to use `loc` values to point to programs and files has been added.